# How does one visualize Abel's test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I remember that at a lecture we had a visual representation of why Abel's test should work but I don't recall how exactly it was. It was somehow representing $a_{n}$ on one axis and $b_{n}$ on another but I don't see yet exactly how it shows that the test works. Could you help me?

Abel's criterion is that $\sum a_{n} b_{n}$ is convergent if $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent and $b_{n}$ is monotone and bounded.